# C#で自作クラスをセットしたListBoxから指定した要素を取り出すには？

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

```
class A
{
  public string name;
  public int age = 0;
  public A(string _name)
  {
    this.name = _name;
  }
}
```

上記の様な自作クラスをListBoxの要素として設定した後、
A.nameが"阿部"等といった要素を取り出し、そのインデクスを
選択状態にするソースを組んでいます。

現段階では、forで一つ一つ回しながらAクラスを拾い、
一つ一つA.nameと比較していくソースになっていますが、
もっと良い方法はありますでしょうか。

http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/programing/arrayfilter.html

こちらのサイト様のように、Arrayクラスを使った方法ができるような
きがするのですが、よく解りませんでした。

未熟な質問で恐れ入りますが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

現在のソースは下記のようになっています。

===========================================================

```
// string[] stArray 表示させるための前段階の文字列配列

this.lstbox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (string s in stArray)
{
　this.lstbox1.Items.Add(new A(s));
}

public string _Value
{
  get
  {
    A a = (A)this.lstbox1.SelectedValue;
    return a.name;
  }
  set
  {
    // ↓この部分をfor,foreachを使わずに行いたい
    foreach(A d in this.lstbox1.Items)
    {
       if (d.name == value)
       {
         this.lstbox1.SelectedValue = d;
         break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`メソッドを使用します。

```
this.lstbox1.SelectedValue = this.lstbox1.Items
                                         .Cast<A>()
                                         .FirstOrDefault(d => d.name == value)
                          ?? this.lstbox1.SelectedValue;
```

なお`?? this.lstbox1.SelectedValue`を指定しないと該当する要素が存在しない場合の動作が変わります。また`Enumerable.First()`を使用すると例外が発生するようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございました!一発で解決です!!いつもありがとうございます。これからもよろしくお願いいたします。